# Iphone TABBAR MENU like documentstogo app

Tags: iphone, menu, tabbar

How can I do a TABBAR MENU like this???

http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/iphone/index.html

Thanks,
Simone

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom view.  It does not use the default tab bar in landscape mode